# How to use powershell to send SQL command to Access DB and return results?

Tags: ms-access, powershell, interface

What are the ways to pull info from an Access DB to powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in cmdlet to do this.  However you still have several options.

1. Use sqlcmd.exe - it stills works in PowerShell
2. [SQL PowerShell Extensions](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/)
3. Use Invoke-AdoCommand - this is in the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com)
4. Drop down to the ADO.NET classes and program it.

Fortunately somebody else has [written up that last one](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/InteractingWithSQLDatabasesInPowerShellInvokeSqlCommand.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You've already got an answer that works but also visit [Richard Siddaway's Blog Of PowerShell and Other Things with the Access tag](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/tags/Access/default.aspx)